# Looping over columns in data.table R

Tags: r, datatable, data.table

I am trying to loop over columns in data.table package in R. I have been having trouble trying to get the for loop to accurately input the column when I subset the datatable.

The goal of my task is to get the number of rows for each subset of the datatable when the column condition of "==1" is met.

Here is my code:

```
data <- data.table(va=c(1,0,1), vb=c(1,0,0), vc=c(1,1,1))


names <- c("va", "vc")

for (col in names) {
    print(nrow(data[col == 1,]))
    print(col)
}
```

Here is the output I get

```
[1] 0
[1] "va"
[1] 0
[1] "vc"
```

Is there something I am missing or a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are subsetting rows. Maybe try `print(nrow(data[, col == 1]))`

Comment: `NULL
[1] "va"
NULL
[1] "vc"` output from that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colSums`, which is much simpler and faster than looping.

```
dt <- data.table(va=c(1,0,1), vb=c(1,0,0), vc=c(1,1,1))
col.names <- c("va", "vc")
dt[, colSums(.SD==1), .SDcols = col.names]
# va vc 
# 2  3
```

**Note:** I changed your object names to `dt` and `col.names` because it is not good practice to use base functions as names.

If you *really* want to use a `for` loop (I don't recommend it, but for educational purposes...) you can fix it using `get` to use the *values* of the column rather than the column *name* itself

```
for (col in col.names) {
  dt[get(col) == 1, print(.N)]
}
```

Comment: That get's me what I'm looking for thanks dww, I still have to figure out why my loop function isn't working